# "Generic" Parameters on model (Java)

Tags: java, c#, data-annotations, hibernate-annotations, model-validation

In C # I could use (on data-annotations) this code below without problems:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^myRegex$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

But in Java it doesn't work, I tried it:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^myRegex$", message = "The field {0} is not in the correct format.")
private String name;
```

The {0} just return {0}, not the "name" field.

So, could someone help me with some example in Java to make it work?